# Why does GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR give an INVALID_ENUM error?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Using XCode 4.4.1 I have the following OpenGL code:

```
//set the tex params
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

I check the OpenGL error using this snippet:

```
GLenum err = glGetError();//THIS IS LIKE THIS BECAUSE OF AN EARLIER ERROR

if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    NSLog(@"glError: 0x%04X", i, err);
}
```

The OpenGL code produces an error (0x500) - I'm targetting iOS 5.0 with OpenGL ES2.0.

Why is this an invalid enum??

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml
This has all the answers you need

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The magnifaction filter [`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) doesn't support mip-mapping, as this just has no meaning for texture magnification. It only supports `GL_NEAREST` and `GL_LINEAR`. So just change this line to

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Is this still valid? 
**The GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR filter mode provides the best quality when texturing but requires additional texels to be fetched from memory.**
From: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html

Comment: @aledalgrande Of course it is still valid. It has always been valid and will always stay valid. That might seem like a bold statement but it isn't, since as said the maginification filter has absolutely no notion of mipmapping at all. Of course `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is very useful, but it is not used for the magnification filter (`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`), but only for the minfication filter (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`). Your link seems to fail to mention this difference, but then again it's really only supplemental material anyway and not supposed to explain texturing in its entirety.